# Discrete Math/Logic Problem used in Computer Science Class: Who Robbed the National Bank?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The following question is supposed to give you insight on how to maintain logic when making programs. Please be open minded as this may not look like a Computer Science Problem, but it definitely contains logic that you will use when making If statements and Booleans, so PLEASE keep that in mind.

### Who Robbed the National Bank?

Inspector Malone knows that the culprit is one and only one of the following: Alex, John, or Sally. He interrogates them. Each makes two statements.

Alex: "It wasn't me." "John did it."

John: "Listen, Alex did it.""And Sally did it."

Sally: "I didn't do it." "Neither did Alex."

Each has made one TRUE statement and one FALSE statement. Who did it?

Comment: I do not really see how is this related to the Computer Science. Puzzle? Yes. Logic? Yes. With nice assumption that the statements of the accused are 100% valid. So this excersise is to change natural language statements to logic and find satisfiable values? What if they lied? (I see the answer right now, so I am even more lost what is it about).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48011/discussion-on-question-by-gabby-quattrone-discrete-math-logic-problem-used-in-co).  Please take further discussion along these lines to that particular chat room.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look over each statement one at a time. Keep in note that each person has a statement which is FALSE, and a statement which is TRUE.

Alex said it wasn't him. John did it.

If Alex was telling the truth that it wasn't him, he can lie about John doing it, which leaves Sally.

In the other case, he lies that it wasn't him, BUT John did it. This is logically impossible, because only one person did it.

So far it looks like Sally's pretty guilty! Let's go to the next statement.

John says Alex did it and so did Sally. If he tells the truth about Alex but lies about Sally, then Alex OR HIMSELF did it. Vice versa, then Sally OR HIMSELF did it.

Last statement. Sally says she didn't do it but neither did Alex. If she told the truth she didn't do it, then Alex did it. If Alex didn't do it, Sally did it.

To sum up, let's look at each statement again.

Alex:
1st Statement: If true, Sally did it.
2nd Statement: If true, logically impossible.

Going off of JUST Alex's statement, we can already confirm that Sally did it.